# That's a good rebus; I don't know if it's worth $5,000 but it's pretty gosh-patootin' good

Tags: rebus, movies

[image: Let me be clear, this is a rebus of unprecedented rebusocity.]

And since this is a movie rebus, if you need a clue:

> [image: har har har]

Comment: Is the title a reference to pulp fiction?

Comment: It is, but it's censored, as homage to the rebus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Frankly my dear, I don't give a damn.

Explanation:

> Frank (furter)
> Lee (Harvey Oswald; credit goes to @Bishop)
> my (little pony|chemical romance)
> deer
> eye
> don't give (under section 506)
> a dam.

Clue:

> Miss Scarlett from Cluedo
>  Mr. Boddy (the butler) from Cluedo
>  Combined clue: Scarlett O'Hara + Rhett Butler

Comment: Correct answer, but you missed the second one (the creepy dude). Also, side note, the clue?

Comment: lol, he's a Libra

Comment: What is section 506?

Comment: If you want to pick common factors of two numbers, you should be using the gcd, not the lcm :(

Comment: The second guy is lee harvey oswald

Comment: @Bishop And I was trying to be sly with my hint...

Comment: @ffao I realized that after i made it :-(

Comment: @D.A.G. https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc506.html

Comment: @corsiKa who is the guy in the clue? I get the clue is supposed to be scarlett o'hara

Comment: @Bishop The dude is Mr. Body, also from Clue, played by Tim Curry.

Comment: @Bishop It's not Mr. Boddy (who was played by Lee Ving) as feelinferrety believes. It is, however, played by Tim Curry from the 1985 movie. I believe that should make it clear who is talking to Scarlett.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh, it all makes sense.